# BuildFire: upload zip file

Tags: buildfire

BuildFire: It will not let me upload the new app because it says I have already used the name? This is my first app? I have changed the name 10x and I get the same error

Comment: Do you mind sharing the Plugin Name?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're referring to uploading a plugin to the developer portal. If that's the case you need to ensure that the pluginName field in the plugin.json file is unique. It not only has to be unique across all of your plugins; it needs to be unique across all plugins in the entire system.

As an example if you want to create a plugin named "YouTube", the name is already in use. Instead you can updated to something similar such as "YouTube Custom".